# Use function argument as loop variable in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, function-definition

`foo` uses function argument as loop variables

```
void foo(int i, int j) {
    for (; i < 5; ++i)
        for (; j < 5; ++j)
            std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
}
```

and `foo(0, 0)` prints

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
```

I was wondering why `i` is always `0`.

Comment: After this sequence ends j increments to 5. Iteration over i continues, but nothing is printed because the second loop gets skipped.

Comment: @S3gfault says. I have added brackets and extra output to make this clear - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Ka7zseKhG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering why i is always 0.

You are mistaken. The variable `i` is changed within the function from `0` to `5`.:)

The problem is that after the first execution of the inner for loop

```
 for (; j < 5; ++j)
        std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
```

the variable `j` becomes equal to `5`. As a result in all other iterations of the outer for loop the inner for loop is skipped.

To get the expected result you could write for example within the function

```
void foo(int i, int j) {
    for (; i < 5; ++i)
        for ( int k = j; k < 5; ++k)
            std::cout << i << " " << k << std::endl;
}
```